# Why do two points in polar coordinates with different degrees coincide?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw two lines from `(0,0)` to `(50:8cm)` and `(80:8cm)` respectively. However, these two lines coincide. I can't figure out why this happens. I would appreciate your help with this situation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,intersections,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-0.5,0) -- (4,0); %x軸
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw [name path=L] (3,-0.5) -- (3,10) node [above,inner sep=1pt] {$L$}; %L
\path [name path=OB'] (O) -- (20:8cm); %OB的延伸線，為了與L相交以取得B的座標
\path [name intersections={of=L and OB', by=B}]; %B
\draw (O) -- (B) node [right,inner sep=1pt] {$B$};
\path [name path=OC'] (O) -- (50:8cm); %OC的延伸線，為了與L相交以取得C的座標
\path [name intersections={of=L and OC', by=C}];
\draw [red] (O) -- (C) node [right,inner sep=1pt] {$C$}; %OC
\path [name path=OA'] (O) -- (80:8cm); %OA的延伸線，為了與L相交以取得A的座標
\path [name intersections={of=L and OA', by=A}];
\draw [dashed] (O) -- (A) node [right,inner sep=1pt] {$A$}; %OA
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path will not extend automatically. So you must give them enough length to make them actually intersect.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,intersections,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-0.5,0) -- (4,0); %x軸
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \path [name path=L] (3, -0.5) -- (3, 20);
  \path [name path=OB'] (O) -- (20:20cm); %OB的延伸線，為了與L相交以取得B的座標
  \path [name path=OC'] (O) -- (50:20cm); %OC的延伸線，為了與L相交以取得C的座標
  \path [name path=OA'] (O) -- (80:20cm); %OA的延伸線，為了與L相交以取得A的座標
  \path [name intersections={of=L and OB', by=B}]; %B
  \path [name intersections={of=L and OC', by=C}];
  \path [name intersections={of=L and OA', by=A}];
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\draw (3,-0.5) -- (3,10) node [above,inner sep=1pt] {$L$}; %L
\draw (O) -- (B) node [right,inner sep=1pt] {$B$};
\draw [red] (O) -- (C) node [right,inner sep=1pt] {$C$}; %OC
\draw [dashed] (O) -- (A) node [right,inner sep=1pt] {$A$}; %OA
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 but you do not need to extend the line, intersections of (continuations of) lines can be computed with `calc`. Try `\path[overlay] (3, -0.5) coordinate (L1) -- (3,10) coordinate (L2)
  (O) -- (20:20cm) coordinate(B') 
  (O) -- (50:20cm) coordinate(C')
  (O) -- (80:20cm) coordinate(A')
  foreach \X in {A,B,C}
  {(intersection of O--\X' and L1--L2) coordinate (\X)};`. Note that `overlay` is a synonym for `pgfinterruptboundingbox`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat it is convenient! But I do not find it in `pgfmanual`, where can I find the detailed explaination?

Comment: Seems like it got removed from the manual (and I do not know why). The `intersection cs` key is still used on p. 123 but, as far as I can see, no longer documented.